# Unable to locate CodeIgniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

I'm trying out codeigniter for the first time on a MAMP deployment however I'm unable to load a model into a controller. The end result is always...

> Unable to locate the model you have specified: second_model

**Controller - welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('second_model');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
}
```

**Model - second_model.php**

```
class Second_model extends Model {
public function __construct()
{
    // model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

}
```

Comment: You should be extending `CI_Model`. Is `extends Model` a typo here, or is that what you are actually using?

Comment: Well that was annoyingly simple, I was using 'extends Model' rather than 'CI_Model' appears to working correctly now. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: I added it as an answer, so you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be extending `CI_Model` rather than `Model`

So:

```
class Second_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```